# How can I give a layer a shadow that will provide depth?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to create a design like the following image:

[image]

I tried to replicate this by creating another layer and changing the blending options (adding a drop shadow) for it. This is the image I ended up with (missed that separation kind of design), I was not satisfied with the results.

[image]

Here are the settings I used for my attempt:

[image]
<sup>[Click image for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyoWg.png)</sup>

**How can I produce the 3D effect done in the first image?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply looks like a standard, almost default, drop shadow layer style.

[image: shadow]

In your case, it would appear you've got the image cropped so tight any shadow won't appear. You need to extend the visible area.